# Set Modelica Derivative Units

Tags: modelica, jmodelica

I know I can define parameter units like so:

```
parameter Modelica.SIunits.Mass m0 = 2 "Mass";
```

And the units of state variables like so:

```
Real m(start=m0, fixed=true, min=0, max=100, unit="kg");
```

But how can I define the units of a derivative? (Or are these generated automatically? It may be that JModelica, which I am using, simply does not check units.)

```
der(m) = m*u;
```

Answer (score 2):

Dymola does this automatically for you. OpenModelica does not. So I guess it's probably something also missing in JModelica.org.

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming you are referring to unit checking. Still, do you know if there is a way to set the derivative units in Dymola? Or are these calculated automagically?

Comment: I meant that it is automatically derived by Dymola.